# How to perform a client-side operation in a controller in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs app and here's one of the methods in a controller:

```
router.get('/my-path', function (req, res, next) {
    //....1
    function render(var1) {
      //some stuff which takes a lot of time
    }

    //....2
    render("something 456");
}
```

which returns **a file**. I want to be able to show some information on the client between "//...1" and "//....2", for simplicity let's say `alert`

How can I do that? If I just put `alert` at "//...1" and "//....2", that will produce an exception.

Comment: What happens exactly when you put `console.log` at //1 and //2?

Comment: it looks like you would like to use nested requests, am i right? if so [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101687/nested-requests-are-blocking) some discussion about it