# JS parase data sending only 100 data in JSON format from table of nearly 8000

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, jira-rest-api, jql

Have a table of 10000 data and fetching particular data from table using query (jql). And the fetched count is correct which is 673 but the when opening those data it is sending only 100 data.
Here is my code:

```
request({
 /////////////////////////////////////
 //query to get current open tickets//
 /////////////////////////////////////
 url: '/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=OWRT AND status in (Open, "In Progress", Reopened)&startAt=0&maxResults=-1',
 success: function(response) {
  var owrt = $.parseJSON(response);
  var liktot = parsedata(response,'owrt');
console.log("OWRT max"+owrt.maxResults);
  request({
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //query to get current resolved and closed tickets//
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   url: '/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=OWRT AND status not in (Open, "In Progress", Reopened)',
   success: function(response1) {
    var fixowrt = $.parseJSON(response1);
    var owrt_tot=owrt.total;
    request({
     //////////////////////////////////////////
     //query to get year 2016 created tickets//
     //////////////////////////////////////////
     url: '/rest/api/2/search?jql=project = OWRT AND created >= 2016-01-01 AND created <= 2016-12-31',
     success: function(response2) {
      var cowrt = $.parseJSON(response2);
      request({
       //////////////////////////////////////////
       //query to get year 2017 created tickets//
       //////////////////////////////////////////
       url: '/rest/api/2/search?jql=project = OWRT AND created >= 2017-01-01 AND created <= 2017-12-31&maxResults=-1',
       success: function(response3) {
    var cfixowrt = $.parseJSON(response3);
        var owrtcre17 = parsedata(response3,'owrt2017');
        var cowrt_tot=cowrt.total;
        request({
     /////////////////////////////////////////
     //query to get year 2016 closed tickets//
     /////////////////////////////////////////
         url: '/rest/api/2/search?jql=project = OWRT AND status = Closed AND updated >= 2016-01-01 AND updated <= 2016-12-31',
     success: function(response4) {
          var fowrt = $.parseJSON(response4);
          request({
       /////////////////////////////////////////
       //query to get year 2017 closed tickets//
       /////////////////////////////////////////
           url: '/rest/api/2/search?jql=project = OWRT AND status = Closed AND updated >= 2017-01-01 AND updated <= 2017-12-31',
       success: function(response5) {
        var ffixowrt = $.parseJSON(response5);
            var fowrt_tot=fowrt.total;
            request({
         ////////////////////////////////////////////
         //query to get all tickets in this project//
         ////////////////////////////////////////////
             url: '/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=OWRT',
         success: function(response6) {
              console.log("start1:"+reqcount);
          var fullowrt = $.parseJSON(response6);
          var fullowrt_tot = fullowrt.total
              var obj = {};
             obj['key']='OWRT';
             obj['tot']=owrt_tot;
             obj['totlink']=liktot[0];
             obj['ntotlink']=liktot[1];
             obj['fixntotlink']=fixowrt.total;
             obj['ckey']='OWRT';
             obj['ctot']=cowrt_tot;
             obj['cre17totlink']=owrtcre17[0];
             obj['cre17ntotlink']=owrtcre17[1];
             obj['cfixntotlink']=cfixowrt.total;
             obj['fkey']='OWRT';
             obj['ftot']=fowrt_tot;
             obj['ffixntotlink']=ffixowrt.total;
             obj['fulltot']=fullowrt.total;
             summary.push(obj);
             reqcount=reqcount+1;
         requestexe(); 
             },
            error: function(response) {
             console.log("Error loading API (" + uri + ")");
             console.log(arguments);
             },
            data: {"fields":["key"]},
            contentType: "application/json"
            });
           requestexe(); 
           },
          error: function(response) {
           console.log("Error loading API (" + uri + ")");
           console.log(arguments);
           },
          data: {"fields":["key"]},
          contentType: "application/json"
          });
         requestexe(); 
         },
        error: function(response) {
         console.log("Error loading API (" + uri + ")");
         console.log(arguments);
         },
        data: {"fields":["key"]},
        contentType: "application/json"
        });
       requestexe(); 
       },
      error: function(response) {
       console.log("Error loading API (" + uri + ")");
       console.log(arguments);
       },
      data: {"fields":["key","id","status","project","issuetype","issuelinks", "summary", "assignee", "type",'created']},
      contentType: "application/json"
      });
     requestexe(); 
     },
    error: function(response) {
     console.log("Error loading API (" + uri + ")");
     console.log(arguments);
     },
    data: {"fields":["key"]},
    contentType: "application/json"
    });
   requestexe(); 
   },
  error: function(response) {
   console.log("Error loading API (" + uri + ")");
   console.log(arguments);
   },
  data: {"fields":["key"]},
  contentType: "application/json"
  });
 requestexe(); 
 },
error: function(response) {
 console.log("Error loading API (" + uri + ")");
 console.log(arguments);
 },
data: {"fields":["key","id","status","project","issuetype","issuelinks", "summary", "assignee", "type",'created']},
contentType: "application/json"
});
```

when look the query the total count which is "owrt_tot" is sending correct but when fectching data from that it is sending only 100 which are includes "liktot[0]" + "liktot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8JJ6.png)".
[the final outcome of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8JJ6.png)

But the total count is 673. But the data sending from the above code is only 100. Before this the total count is upto 1000 after few days keep running the code lead me to 100. So is there anything that memory is a problem or need to change the code?

Comment: Nesting your requests not only is VERY error prone but it looks terrible. I'd consider you split your requests first and check your results after that. Maybe your error resolves itself. Otherwise, feel free to post the refactored version please. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101687/nested-requests-are-blocking?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with JIRA atlassian api. Verified with atlassian support they purposefully restricted